# Can we restore proper order to $[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, \dotsc]$ via "rotations" ($a, b, c \to b,c,a$)?

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

I have the infinite list of numbers 
$$[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, \ldots]$$

It is the set of the natural numbers with the one difference that the two numbers $2$ and $1$ are flipped. The aim of the puzzle is to have every number in its correct position (so in the end we want to have exactly the set of natural numbers). There is one change that is allowed to made:
It is allowed to rotate 3 numbers that are next to each other in this form:
$$\ldots, a, b, c, \ldots \quad\to\quad \ldots, b, c, a, \ldots$$

so a example after the first rotation could be:
$$[1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, \ldots]$$

Is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Do you know about odd permutations?

Comment: No. I'm going to start doing some research ...

Comment: It seems to me that this can be solved by applying the $n$th rotation on the numbers in the places $n,n+1,n+2$.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo Hm i don't get it. when i say n=1 i get 1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8,.. after the third rotation

Comment: Look up "parity" of a permutation. Your initial state is a single transposition away from the goal making it an odd permutation, but the moves you allow are products of two transpositions, so are even. The fact that you have an infinite set here means you have to be a little careful, but since you are only allowed finitely many moves, they will all take place in some finite subset of the naturals anyway, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip: That looks like an answer to me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up "parity" of a permutation. Your initial state is a single transposition away from the goal, making it an odd permutation, but the moves you allow are products of two transpositions, so are even. The fact that you have an infinite set here means you have to be a little careful, but since you are only allowed finitely many moves, they will all take place in some finite subset of the naturals anyway, so that's not a problem.

Comment: so the answer is: there is a finite solution for this problem?

Comment: No there is no solution since an odd permutation cannot be written as a product of even permutations.